# how to get a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters instagram rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems, instagram

I'm using oauth2 with devise and trying to login with instagram. But, when I login, it gives me this error:

```
You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters
```

I have placed the client id in my application.yml file but its not working

instagram.rb

```
Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = ENV['CLIENT_ID']
  config.client_secret = ENV['CLIENT_SECRET']
end
```

callbacks_controller.rb

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def instagram
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end
end
```

application.yml

```
CLIENT_ID : "221ea35dc7c1489c946e2f3062e8984a"
CLIENT_SECRET: "e8a100e6f1d44842a26f6bf7c4c5a063"
REDIRECT_URI : "http://localhost:3000/users/auth/instagram/callback"
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
  root 'products#index'
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,     :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:instagram]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end  
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: It seems like your app can't find these ENV variables. I don't think application.yml is the right place to put your ENV variables unless you're using a gem such as [envyable](https://github.com/philnash/envyable)?

Comment: Are those spaces (e.g., `CLIENT_ID :` right before the colon) really in your `application.yml` file? Or is that just copy-paste error? Not sure if that could be giving you problems... (Also, I assume you're using Figaro or as @pierrea said, some other gem for managing ENV variables.)

Comment: Ok got it to work do you know how to make custom route for instagram login in views ?

Comment: <% if user_signed_in? %>
    Welcome <%=  current_user.email %>
    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path%> or <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %>

    <%= link_to "Sign u inp", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:instagram) %> 'code'